# Selenium 2 - getting the selected option from drop down list

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
<select class="selectCity">
<option></option>
<option value="Paris">Paris</option>
<option>New York</option>
<option>London</option>
</select>



    Select op1 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[@id='cityTable']//*[contains(@class,'selectCity')])")));
    List<WebElement> allSelectedOptions = op1.getAllSelectedOptions();
    WebElement firstSelectedOption = op1.getFirstSelectedOption();
    System.out.println("op1!!!!!"+firstSelectedOption.getText());
```

The user selected option on the web page is London.

Put the output is op1!!!!!

How to find the option that has been selected on the web page?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like it is returning the selected option. If no option is explicitly selected (ie html is <option selected>), then the first option is considered selected. In this case, your first option has no text, which is why `firstSelectedOption.getText()` is blank.

Answer (score 0):

`Selenium.getSelectedLabel("//string locator");`

The above code helps in knowing the option witch is currently selected and visible from the drop down list.

String locator of drop down box can by anything eg:- name,id,xpath

EG : `Selenium.getSelectedLabel("name=productIdxSel");`